# QT5.3 installer for windows throws error ' is not a valid win32 application'

Tags: windows, qt

I am trying to install QT5.3 on my windows machine with MinGW. When I try install, it throws an error saying

"qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw482_opengl-5.3.0.exe is not a valid win32 application."

I also tried the online installer, but as my network is not that fast, the installation doesn't go beyond 20% and takes huge time.

Any solution to this would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Vrushali

Comment: Maybe the downloaded file is corrupted?

Answer (score 1):

The downloaded file is almost certainly corrupted. You have to download it again. I suppose you can ask someone to download it and put it on a DVD for you.